# Change an observation in a TimeSeries

Tags: time-series

What is the proper way to change one observation in a TimeSeries object?

Let's say there a time series:

```
ts = TimeSeries[Transpose[{Range[10], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}]]
```

Now, I need to alter the 2nd observation to some value like 3.

```
ts[2] = 3
(*produces error: TemporalData is Protected *)
```

Now, I can define something like this:

```
  TimeSeriesAssign[ts_, v_] := TimeSeries[
     ts["DatePath"] /. {DateObject[First@v], _} :> {DateObject@First@v, 
       Last@v}]
```

...which does the job:

```
ts = TimeSeriesAssign[ts, {2, 3}]
ts[2]
(*3*)
```

But is there a better, preferably built-in way to make assignments to TimeSeries object's observations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TimeSeriesInsert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesInsert.html):

> - `TimeSeriesInsert[tseries, {t, v}]` inserts a value `v` at time `t`
>     in the time series `tseries`.
> - If a value is already present at time `t` it will be replaced by `v`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
ts = TimeSeries[Transpose[{Range[10], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}]];
ts2 = TimeSeriesInsert[ts, {2, 3}];

ListLinePlot[{ts, ts2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"ts", "ts2"}]
```

[image]

You can check if a value at time `t` exists before making the change:

```
ClearAll[tsInsert]
tsInsert = If[MemberQ[ts["Times"], First@#2], TimeSeriesInsert[#, #2], #] &;

tsInsert[ts, {2, 3}] == ts2
```

> True

Comment: thanks!! that is exactly what I was looking for (and should have found myself)

Comment: @iav, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Can this code be modified to change more than one value?